I have a problem with removed records in Excel using Openpyxl
Today at work, I decided to use Openpyxl for the first time so that my colleagues don't have to do manual work filling out Excel spreadsheets.
The code I wrote works fine, but when I try to insert the following formula, it can't do it.
Formula:

ws[‘D11’] = r‘=IF(AND(AND(LEFT(’drive ‘!B2, 4)=\’Gig \‘,OR(MID(’drive‘!B2, 6, 3)=\’500\‘, MID(’drive'!B2, 6, 3)=\‘800\’, MID(‘drive’!B2, 6, 4)=\‘1000\’)), MEDIAN(IF(‘drive’!$B$2:$B$136=‘drive’!B2, ‘drive’!$C$2:$C$136))),)’

What could be the error? It's supposed to be an array formula, but it didn't work with it either.....
It's possible that I'm making a mistake in the apostrophes, but I've been trying to solve this problem for the past few hours and just can't.
What the code works with:
Created an Excel document with multiple sheets. Two of them contain information on which the calculation takes place, and the third sheet is completely empty. There by means of Python are inserted formulas that, when you run the code, automatically count the result in their cells.
I expect the code to return me the median value calculated from the data in the ‘drive’ sheet.
If anyone knows a simpler solution, I'd love to have it.

With formulae like these it's best to look at the xml source to see extaly how Excel stores the formula. But a raw string together with backslashes is wrong. Just use double quotes and single quotes. And, if it is an Array formula, use one.

@CharlieClark Thanks for the tip, I'll definitely give it a try when I get home!

Is your sheet name "drive"? there is no space, no bracket in the sheet name? if so, I think the formula should just be '=MID(drive!B2, 6, 3)', that is, no single quote around it.

@rachel Thank you! I didn't even think about the fact that the name of the sheet could change the picture so much! Indeed, it was not just a ‘drive’ but a ‘drive m’. And that's what caused my formula to not work.

You can use utils.quote_sheetname(wb['drive m'].title) if your sheet name is "drive m".

Oh, good! I'll keep that in mind.

I write the formula
=IF(AND(AND(LEFT(drive!B2, 4)="Gig",OR(MID(drive!B2, 6, 3)="500", MID(drive!B2, 6, 3)="800", MID(drive!B2, 6, 4)="1000")), MEDIAN(IF(drive!$B$2:$B$136=drive!B2, drive!$C$2:$C$136))),)
in Excel. save it. unzip it. Goto /Book1/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml. I saw it is stored like this:

So below code should work:
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.worksheet.formula import ArrayFormula
from openpyxl import utils

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("formula.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet']
reference_ws = wb['drive']
quote_sheetname = utils.quote_sheetname(reference_ws.title)

ws["A1"] = ArrayFormula("A1", f'=IF(AND(AND(LEFT({quote_sheetname}!B2, 4)="Gig",OR(MID({quote_sheetname}!B2, 6, 3)="500", MID({quote_sheetname}!B2, 6, 3)="800", MID({quote_sheetname}!B2, 6, 4)="1000")), MEDIAN(IF({quote_sheetname}!$B$2:$B$136={quote_sheetname}!B2, {quote_sheetname}!$C$2:$C$136))),)')

wb.save("formula.xlsx")

Edited, I update drive in the formula to utils.quote_sheetname(reference_ws.title)

FWIW I would suggest always using the utitliy quote_sheetname(ws.title) in references.

@CharlieClark yes, that is much better.

Thanks so much for the tips everyone! It was thanks to you that I realised what the mistake was.
When writing a formula in Python, it asks for apostrophes on both sides of it, which broke my reference to another sheet in this document (which was really called not just ‘drive’, but ‘drive m’). The double quotes didn't save the situation, because with them Python itself no longer counted the reference as a reference. As soon as I manually renamed the sheet from ‘drive m’ to ‘drivem’ everything worked.
The final formula looks like this:
ws[‘D9’] = ArrayFormula(‘D9’, ‘=IF(AND(AND(LEFT(drivm!B2, 4)=’Giga‘, OR(MID(drivm!B2, 6, 3)=’500’, MID(drivm! B2, 6, 3)=‘800’, MID(drivm!B2, 6, 4)=‘1000’)), MEDIAN(IF(drivm!$B$2:$B$136=drivm!B2, drivm!$C$2:$C$136))),'))

